# SVG on hover effect not working when change index run time

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have added my j Query Code which is change the index on hover g tag of SVG ..
its working fine in chrome but not in Firefox

Open this code in chrome and then run you will see like every line will change on top of other 2 line

But its not working in firefox.  Please help

```js
  $('.bus').hover(function(){
  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
 });
```

```css
line{stroke: #ccc;stroke-dasharray: 0;stroke-width: 5;}

.color1:hover line, .color1.active line {stroke:#913ccd; pointer-events:all;}
.color1:hover .trip_start_icon path, .color1.active .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#913ccd;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6; pointer-events:all; }
.color1 .trip_start_icon path, .color1.active .trip_start_icon path{fill:#913ccd; pointer-events:all;}
.color1:hover circle, .color1.active circle{fill:#913ccd; pointer-events:all;}


.color2:hover line {stroke:#f15f74;}
.color2:hover .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#f15f74;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.color2 .trip_start_icon path{fill:#f15f74;}
.color2:hover circle{fill:#f15f74;}

.color3:hover line {stroke:#f76d3c;}
.color3:hover .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#f76d3c;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.color3 .trip_start_icon path{fill:#f76d3c;}
.color3:hover circle{fill:#f76d3c;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg  id="mainSVG" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph" width="100%" height="500">
       <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="10%" x2="10%" y1="0" y2="100%"></line>
       </g>
       <g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
        <line y1="0" y2="100%" x1="90%" x2="90%"></line>
       </g>
       <g class="line-left"></g>
       <g class="line-right"></g>
       
       <g class="labels labels-left y-labels"></g>
       <g class="labels labels-right y-labels"></g>
       
       <g id="line1" class="grid bus color1">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="15" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="10%" y1="30" x2="90%" y2="90"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="90" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="90" x2="10%" y2="180"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="180" x2="90%" y2="270"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="270" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="270" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="450"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="450" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="450" x2="10%" y2="540"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        
       </g>
       
       <g id="line2" class="grid bus color2">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="75" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="10%" y1="90" x2="90%" y2="150"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="150" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="150" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="330"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="330" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="330" x2="10%" y2="420"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="420" x2="90%" y2="510"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="510" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="510" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
       </g>
       
       <g id="line3" class="grid bus color3">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="90%" y="45" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path fill="#5C9741" d="M0,15.355l7.324-7.321c4.045-4.045,10.602-4.045,14.646,0c4.041,4.042,4.041,10.599,0,14.644   c-4.045,4.045-10.602,4.045-14.646,0L0,15.355z"></path> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="90%" y1="60" x2="10%" y2="120"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="120" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="120" x2="90%" y2="180"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="180" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="300"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="300" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="300" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="420"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="420" x2="10%" y2="480"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="480" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="480" x2="90%" y2="540"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="540" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="600" x2="90%" y2="660"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="660" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
       </g>
       
       
      </svg>
```

Comment: Moving the elements around in the DOM is obviously messing with Firefox's handling of the mouse events.  If you can live with the highlighted lines being covered by the grey ones, then the easy solution is to just remove the JS. Otherwise a more complicated solution is required.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if still face any issue then let me know

```css
line{stroke: #ccc;stroke-dasharray: 0;stroke-width: 1;}

.color1:hover line, .color1.active line {stroke:#913ccd; pointer-events:all;}
.color1:hover .trip_start_icon path, .color1.active .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#913ccd;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6; pointer-events:all; }
.color1 .trip_start_icon path, .color1.active .trip_start_icon path{fill:#913ccd; pointer-events:all;}
.color1:hover circle, .color1.active circle{fill:#913ccd; pointer-events:all;}


.color2:hover line {stroke:#f15f74;}
.color2:hover .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#f15f74;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.color2 .trip_start_icon path{fill:#f15f74;}
.color2:hover circle{fill:#f15f74;}

.color3:hover line {stroke:#f76d3c;}
.color3:hover .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#f76d3c;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.color3 .trip_start_icon path{fill:#f76d3c;}
.color3:hover circle{fill:#f76d3c;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg  id="mainSVG" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph" width="100%" height="500">
       <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="10%" x2="10%" y1="0" y2="100%"></line>
       </g>
       <g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
        <line y1="0" y2="100%" x1="90%" x2="90%"></line>
       </g>
       <g class="line-left"></g>
       <g class="line-right"></g>
       
       <g class="labels labels-left y-labels"></g>
       <g class="labels labels-right y-labels"></g>
       
       <g id="line1" class="grid bus color1">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="15" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="10%" y1="30" x2="90%" y2="90"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="90" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="90" x2="10%" y2="180"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="180" x2="90%" y2="270"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="270" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="270" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="450"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="450" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="450" x2="10%" y2="540"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        
       </g>
       
       <g id="line2" class="grid bus color2">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="75" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="10%" y1="90" x2="90%" y2="150"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="150" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="150" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="330"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="330" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="330" x2="10%" y2="420"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="420" x2="90%" y2="510"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="510" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="510" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
       </g>
       
       <g id="line3" class="grid bus color3">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="90%" y="45" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path fill="#5C9741" d="M0,15.355l7.324-7.321c4.045-4.045,10.602-4.045,14.646,0c4.041,4.042,4.041,10.599,0,14.644   c-4.045,4.045-10.602,4.045-14.646,0L0,15.355z"></path> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="90%" y1="60" x2="10%" y2="120"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="120" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="120" x2="90%" y2="180"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="180" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="300"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="300" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="300" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="420"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="420" x2="10%" y2="480"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="480" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="480" x2="90%" y2="540"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="540" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="600" x2="90%" y2="660"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="660" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
       </g>
       
       
      </svg>
```

Comment: (a) What did you do? Your answer isn't helpful if you don't explain what change you made (and why), and (b) If you just removed the JS, then you have changed the behaviour of the OPs code.  There may be an important reason for moving the group to the top that you are neglecting.

Comment: Sorry actually I got your point I just proved js but its not a good solution, give some time I will try for other

Comment: And Can you please confirm why you use this JS
       $('.bus').hover(function(){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
      });

Comment: I imagine it is because OP doesn't want the highlighted lines to have grey ones going over the top of them.

Comment: Yes you got it so just remove that js then it works fine . I have check in all browser

Comment: if i removed js then hover line will not show on top position
Let me bold the line then you will get idea.

Comment: Please check now in chrome and firefox you will get better idea why i use that JS

Comment: i issue is when i hover line then it should be on top its fixed in chrome but not in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.  I've moved the lines into their own group.  That way they can be moved in the DOM without affecting the mouse events over the `trip_start_icon` element.

However now that the lines are no longer children of the hovered element, we have to simulate the hover state by adding and removing the class "active" from the corresponding lines group.

```js
$('.trip_start_icon').mouseenter(function(){
  var busId = $(this).closest(".bus").attr("id");
  var lineGroup = $(".lines."+busId);
  lineGroup.addClass("active");
  lineGroup.parent().append(lineGroup);
});

$('.trip_start_icon').mouseleave(function(){
  var busId = $(this).closest(".bus").attr("id");
  $(".lines."+busId).removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
line {stroke: #ccc;stroke-dasharray: 0; stroke-width: 5;}

.color1 .trip_start_icon path {fill:#913ccd;}
.color1:hover .trip_start_icon path {stroke:#913ccd; stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6; }
.line1.active line {stroke:#913ccd;}
.line1.active circle{fill:#913ccd;}

.color2 .trip_start_icon path {fill:#f15f74;}
.color2:hover .trip_start_icon path {stroke:#f15f74; stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.line2.active line {stroke:#f15f74;}
.line2.active circle{fill:#f15f74;}

.color3 .trip_start_icon path {fill:#f76d3c;}
.color3:hover .trip_start_icon path {stroke:#f76d3c; stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.line3.active line {stroke:#f76d3c;}
.line3.active circle{fill:#f76d3c;}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<svg  id="mainSVG" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph" width="100%" height="500">
  <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
    <line x1="10%" x2="10%" y1="0" y2="100%"></line>
  </g>
  <g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
    <line y1="0" y2="100%" x1="90%" x2="90%"></line>
  </g>
  <g class="line-left"></g>
  <g class="line-right"></g>
              
  <g class="labels labels-left y-labels"></g>
  <g class="labels labels-right y-labels"></g>
              
  <g id="line1" class="grid bus color1">
    <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="15" width="30" height="30">
      <g id="Layer_1">
        <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
  <g class="line1 lines">
    <line x1="10%" y1="30" x2="90%" y2="90"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="90" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="90" x2="10%" y2="180"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="180" x2="90%" y2="270"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="270" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="270" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="450"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="450" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="450" x2="10%" y2="540"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
  </g>
              
  <g id="line2" class="grid bus color2">
    <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="75" width="30" height="30">
      <g id="Layer_1">
        <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
  <g class="line2 lines">
    <line x1="10%" y1="90" x2="90%" y2="150"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="150" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="150" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="330"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="330" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="330" x2="10%" y2="420"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="420" x2="90%" y2="510"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="510" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="510" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
  </g>
              
  <g id="line3" class="grid bus color3">
    <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="90%" y="45" width="30" height="30">
      <g id="Layer_1">
        <path fill="#5C9741" d="M0,15.355l7.324-7.321c4.045-4.045,10.602-4.045,14.646,0c4.041,4.042,4.041,10.599,0,14.644   c-4.045,4.045-10.602,4.045-14.646,0L0,15.355z"></path>  
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
  <g class="line3 lines">
    <line x1="90%" y1="60" x2="10%" y2="120"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="120" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="120" x2="90%" y2="180"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="180" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="300"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="300" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="300" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="420"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="420" x2="10%" y2="480"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="480" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="480" x2="90%" y2="540"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="90%" y1="540" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
    <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
    <line x1="10%" y1="600" x2="90%" y2="660"></line>
    <circle cx="90%" cy="660" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
  </g>

</svg>
```

*Note that you need to use jQuery v3 or later for `addClass()` to work properly on SVG elements.

Comment: Thank you so much Paul.. Its works but its seems you break my layout, Its hard to manage it but i am trying to set you code in my layout will let you know if its done 

Thankx for Help

Comment: I have done some fixes with your code and done it with my own code Thank you so much... i am updating my code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('.bus').mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).addClass('hover');
 this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
});

$('.bus').mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
line{stroke: #ccc;stroke-dasharray: 0;stroke-width: 5;}

.color1.hover line {stroke:#913ccd;}
.color1.hover .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#913ccd;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.color1 .trip_start_icon path{fill:#913ccd;}
.color1.hover circle{fill:#913ccd;}

.color2.hover line {stroke:#f15f74;}
.color2.hover .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#f15f74;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.color2 .trip_start_icon path{fill:#f15f74;}
.color2.hover circle{fill:#f15f74;}

.color3.hover line {stroke:#f76d3c;}
.color3.hover .trip_start_icon path{stroke:#f76d3c;stroke-width: 3; fill:#C9CCD6;}
.color3 .trip_start_icon path{fill:#f76d3c;}
.color3.hover circle{fill:#f76d3c;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<svg  id="mainSVG" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph" width="100%" height="500">
       <g class="grid x-grid" id="xGrid">
        <line x1="10%" x2="10%" y1="0" y2="100%"></line>
       </g>
       <g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
        <line y1="0" y2="100%" x1="90%" x2="90%"></line>
       </g>
       <g class="line-left"></g>
       <g class="line-right"></g>
       
       <g class="labels labels-left y-labels"></g>
       <g class="labels labels-right y-labels"></g>
       
       <g id="line1" class="grid bus color1">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="15" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="10%" y1="30" x2="90%" y2="90"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="90" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="90" x2="10%" y2="180"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="180" x2="90%" y2="270"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="270" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="270" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="450"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="450" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="450" x2="10%" y2="540"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        
       </g>
       
       <g id="line2" class="grid bus color2">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="6%" y="75" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path id="path2" d="M19.678,22c-4.045,4.044-10.601,4.044-14.646,0 c-4.042-4.045-4.042-10.602,0-14.644c4.045-4.045,10.601-4.045,14.646,0l7.324,7.321L19.678,22z" fill="#5C9741" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" /> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="10%" y1="90" x2="90%" y2="150"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="150" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="150" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="330"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="330" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="330" x2="10%" y2="420"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="420" x2="90%" y2="510"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="510" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="510" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
       </g>
       
       <g id="line3" class="grid bus color3">
        <svg class="trip_start_icon" x="90%" y="45" width="30" height="30">
         <g id="Layer_1">
           <path fill="#5C9741" d="M0,15.355l7.324-7.321c4.045-4.045,10.602-4.045,14.646,0c4.041,4.042,4.041,10.599,0,14.644   c-4.045,4.045-10.602,4.045-14.646,0L0,15.355z"></path> 
         </g>
        </svg>
        <line x1="90%" y1="60" x2="10%" y2="120"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="120" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="120" x2="90%" y2="180"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="180" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="180" x2="10%" y2="240"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="240" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="240" x2="90%" y2="300"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="300" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="300" x2="10%" y2="360"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="360" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="360" x2="90%" y2="420"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="420" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="420" x2="10%" y2="480"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="480" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="480" x2="90%" y2="540"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="540" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="90%" y1="540" x2="10%" y2="600"></line>
        <circle cx="10%" cy="600" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
        <line x1="10%" y1="600" x2="90%" y2="660"></line>
        <circle cx="90%" cy="660" r="4" stroke="none" fill="none" />
       </g>
       
       
      </svg>
```